# All combined docker logs with container name

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-logs

So I am trying to get the combined output of all the container logs with its container name in a log file
`docker logs --tail -3 <id>` with  `**container name** >> logst.log` file.

Answer (score 1):

docker logs takes a single command so you would have to run them for each container. I guess I could do something along:

```
docker ps --format='{{.Names}}' | xargs -P0 -d '\n' -n1 sh -c 'docker logs "$1" | sed "s/^/$1: /"' _
```

- `docker ps --format='{{.Names}}'` - print container names
- `xargs` - for input

  - `-d '\n'` - for each line
  - `-P0` - execute in parallel with any count of parallel jobs

    - remove this option if you don't intent to do `docker logs --follow`
    - it may cause problems, consider adding `stdbuf -oL` and `sed -u` to unbuffer the streams
  - `-n1` - pass one argument to the underyling process
  - `sh -c 'script' _` - execute script for each line with line passed as first positional argument

    - `docker logs "$1"` - get the logs
    - `sed 's/^/$1: /'` - prepend the name of the docker name to each log line

But a way better and industrial grade solution would be to forward docker logs to `journalctl` or other logging solution and use that utility to aggregate and filter logs.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
for i in `docker ps -a -q --format "table {{.ID}}"`; do { docker ps -a -q --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\n" | grep "$i" & docker logs --timestamps --tail  1 "$i"; } >> logs.log; done
```

`logs.log` is a generic file name.